# corrupted zip with readfile

Tags: php, zip, readfile, unlink

I'm using this code to have users download all files in a given directory:

```
<?php

set_time_limit();
$zipname = getcwd();
$zipname = substr($zipname,strrpos($zipname,'/')+1);
$zipname = $zipname.'.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('./'.basename($zipname).'', ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($dir_handle = opendir('./')) {
      while (false !== ($entry = readdir($dir_handle))) {
    if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && !strstr($entry,'.php')) {
        $zip->addFile($entry);
    }
  }
  closedir($dir_handle);
}
else {
die('file not found');
}

$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($zipname).'"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
header('Location: ./'.$zipname);
?>
```

The code works perfectly, but I wanted to delete from the server after the user downloads it, so I tried by just adding

```
unlink($zipname);
```

in the last line. Obviously I got a File not found error.

Then I tried replacing the last header with

```
readfile($zipname);
```

and the download starts, but the zip file downloaded is somehow corrupted and will not unzip.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

That's because `$zipname` is just `.zip` after your substr call.

example:
https://3v4l.org/7L515

Do this instead:

```
$zipname = dirname(__FILE__).".zip";
```

also, this sounds like a bad idea to begin with.

Comment: `$zipname` is actually something like `lastfoldername.zip`. the code creates the file on the server. the name of the file is correct, it's the zip that is corrupted, but only when using `readfile()`.

Comment: If thats the case and youre sure the file is ok then  the only thing left to cause the issue is the headers youre using. Google for the corrct headers for serving archive files.

Comment: if i use the `header('Location: ./'.$zipname);` instead of `readfile($zipname)` the file downloads and unzips with no issues. I need the `readfile()`thing to use `unlink()`and delete the zip after download

Comment: Try octect/stream as the contrnt type header

Comment: i've been testing it without calling `unlink($zipname)`, but if I it put directly below `readfile($zipname)`, the zip gets correctly deleted from the server. so I assume that the unlink is working...